# Is it possible to adjust the font size of an edge label in Python's igraph?

Tags: python, formatting, label, igraph

I'm trying to adjust the font size of my edge labels in Python's igraph package, but once I try to add in label size attributes, the labels that were formerly there disappear. I can't find anything about edge label size in the igraph documentation, and I'm wondering if it's just not possible to do what I'm trying to do. Here's some non-reproducible pseudocode to illustrate:

```
G = ig.Graph(directed=True)
outgoing = G.es.select(..., ...) 
incoming = G.es.select(..., ...)

outgoing["label"] = ...
incoming["label"] = ...
# once I add these lines... **, the labels disappear
outgoing["label_size"] = 2
incoming["label_size"] = 3

visual_style["edge_label"] = G.es["label"]
visual_style["edge_label_size"] = G.es["label_size"]

ig.plot(G, **visual_style)
```

Would appreciate any thoughts on this, and if anyone knows where I might find this in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correctly, but assigning really tiny sizes.

Let's first draw a graph with default properties, which has a point size of 12.

```py
import igraph

g = igraph.Graph([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)])
g.vs["label"] = [1, 2, 3]
g.es["label"] = "edge"

layout = g.layout("fr")
igraph.plot(g, "graph_default.png", layout = layout, bbox=(200, 200))
```

which yields the following image.

[image: Original graph]

After changing the edge label sizes

```py
g.es[0]["label_size"] = 2
g.es[2]["label_size"] = 24

layout = g.layout("fr")
igraph.plot(g, "graph_scaled.png", layout = layout, bbox=(200, 200))
```

this becomes:

[image]

where one edge has almost disappeared.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I know it's not polite to ask another question in the comments, but you seem knowledgeable and I was having trouble finding anything about label positioning in the documentation. Is that a changeable attribute as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a changeable attribute. The only way would be to implement a concrete [`AbstractEdgeDrawer`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.drawing.edge.AbstractEdgeDrawer-class.html#get_label_position) with custom `get_label_position`, use it to initialise a [`DefaultGraphDrawer`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.drawing.graph.DefaultGraphDrawer-class.html) and pass that to the `plot` function.